# How to get page views for a batch of page names from google analytics API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-analytics, google-api, google-api-python-client

I have run the introduction code for Python, and it works.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py

Inside the Analytics Web App I can find a page by `Page Title` and there I have metrics like pageView and avg. time on page.

Now, I would like to query the analytics API to get the same metrics for a batch of `Page Title`s. 
The use is for dataset creation, so I will just run this query a couple of times.

I find the documentation confusing, so any help that would point me in the right direction would help.

Thank you

Comment: what you need is dimension filter as page title is dimension. You can try referring to this official doc https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#dimensionfilterclause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query google analytics using below standard json as input to `batchGet` method

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
{
  "viewId": "",
  "dateRanges": [
    {
      "startDate": "",
      "endDate": ""
    }
  ],
  "metrics": [
    {
      "expression": ""
    }
  ],
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": ""
    }
  ],
  "dimensionFilterClauses": [
    {
      "filters": [
        {
          "expressions": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
  ]
}
```

in `expressions`, you can add a list of queries you would like to give.

This is basic query structure which will be using `OR` as `FilterLogicalOperator`
But, In case you want to add more then specify `operator` with `expressions`

Below is the list of specifications you can give:
[image: GA]

Comment: I have tried to explain more here : https://www.javacodemonk.com/python-get-google-analytics-data-2f738f81